# How to test Post MVC endpoint which requires PDF Multipart file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test

i have MVC Controller with such a method :

```
 @PostMapping("/uploadfiles")
public String uploadMultiplePdfs(@Valid FormModel formModel,
                                 BindingResult bindingResult,
                                 @RequestParam("pdfs")
                                         MultipartFile[] pdfs) throws IOException {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "main";
    }

    //(here is some code for saving pdfs into database and other logic)

    return "redirect:/pdflist";
}
```

I want to test it. I have:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc

public class MvcLayerTest {

//here lots of autowired beans

@Test
 public void uploadResponse() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile ("file", "Hello",MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE, "hello world".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));    
        this.mockMvc.perform(multipart("/uploadfiles").file(mockMultipartFile)).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());
    }
```

Unfortunately this test doesn't pass. What am I doing wrong ? Thank you for any help. I'am getting error info:

*Caused by:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pdfmerger.entity.UploadedFileModel' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 72 more*
```

However UploadedFileModel is Autowired into this test class.
UploadedFileModel is just a simple entity:

```
 @Entity @Table(name = "UPLOADED_PDF")
    
    //lombok annotations
 @Data
 public class UploadedFileModel {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "PDF_ID")
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
        private String id;
        @Column(name = "PDF_NAME")
        private String pdfName;
        @Column(name = "FILE_TYPE")
        private String fileType;
        @Column(name = "PDF_SIZE")
        private long size;
        @Lob
        @Column(name = "PDF_DATA")
        private byte[] pdfData;
    
        public UploadedFileModel() {
        }
    
        public UploadedFileModel(String pdfName, String fileType, Long size, byte[] pdfData) {
            this.pdfName = pdfName;
            this.fileType = fileType;
            this.pdfData = pdfData;
            this.size = size;
        } }
```

Comment: May you add more info like what is the error you are getting?

Comment: `UploadFileModel` bean is some service or component? can you update with complete code in problem?

Comment: The `UploadFileModel` is an entity class, there is no bean created for this class by spring, it won't inject into your controller class.

Comment: Thx for help code_mechanic